# javascript calling Json Parse from the parsed object

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

I have a Javascript class in ES6, and I want to write a LoadFromJson method.

the problem is that JSON.parse return an object and I cannot write :

```
//MyObject.loadFromJson method
loadFromJson(JsonString)
 {
   this=JSON.parse(jsonString); //INVALID//
 }
```

How can I achieve this from within my class.
I know I could write :

```
myObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

but that's not what I want, I need :

```
myObject = new MyObjectClass();
myObject.loadFromJson(JsonString);
```

I want to implement an "undo mechanism" in my object and to be able to save / restore the object.

Comment: Just curious, why can't you do myObject=JSON.parse(jsonString) and need a separate loadFromJson method?

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign to `this`. Here is an example that copies all the attributes from the parsed object.

```
class MyObjectClass {
  loadFromJSON(jsonString) {
    const parsed = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    for (const key in parsed) this[key] = parsed[key];
  }
}

const myObject = new MyObjectClass();
myObject.loadFromJSON('{"a":2,"b":null,"c":"abc"}');
console.log(myObject);
```